# Can't add all the numbers in my Array togheter

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I'm going to sum all the numbers in my Array.
It worked when i had fewer numbers like (12,8,3) etc but now the Array just seems to come back again and again because of the for(var i). 
I don't know any other ways to do this and i would appriciate if if i got any help.

```
var tall:Array = new Array(34,53,2,3,34,26,26,85,3,4,98,2,12);

for(var i:int = 0;i<tall.length;i++)    
{
    trace(tall[i])    
    sum = sum + tall[i];
}
var sum:int = 0;

for each(var nummer:int in tall)    
{
    sum = sum + tall;    
    trace(tall);
}
trace("summen er " + sum);
```

Comment: isn't `sum = sum + tall;` wrong, don't you want `sum = sum + nummer;` ? (maybe "number" too...). Also, you don't trace the first loop result... before `var sum:int = 0;`.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Do you suggest that i delete trace(tall[i])? And where did you want me to put Number?

Comment: You should add `var sum:int = 0;` before the first look, and add `trace("summen er " + sum);` after the first loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is generally fine, just about the second part where you should add the `nummer` to your `sum` ( not the array itself ), and of course, to get the sum of all your array's values, you need only one `for` loop.

About the declaration of the `sum` var, you can do it like what you did without problem because

> ... you can read or write to a variable before it is declared, as long as it is declared before the function ends. This is because of a technique called hoisting , which means that the compiler moves all variable declarations to the top of the function.

For more about that, take a look on the 5th paragraph of this [topic](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f8c).

But it's better to start by declaring all your variables before use them to get a more organised code an to avoid that you forget to declare some of them later.

So your code can be like this :

**vars declaration:**

```
var tall:Array = [34, 53, 2, 3, 34, 26, 26, 85, 3, 4, 98, 2, 12];
var sum:int = 0;
```

**using a for loop :**

```
for(var i:int = 0; i< tall.length; i++)
{
    sum = sum + tall[i];
}
```

**using a for each loop :**

```
for each(var nummer:int in tall)
{
    sum = sum + nummer;
}
```

and for both loops, `sum` is :

```
trace(sum);     // gives : 382
```

For more, you can take a look on :

- [Learning ActionScript 3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning.html).
- [ActionScript 3 Variables](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/variables.html).
- [ActionScript 3 Arrays](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/arrays.html).
- [ActionScript 3 Loops](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/loops.html).

Hope that can help.